# ActiveSupport overrides #to_json behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, activesupport

How to teach ActiveSupport to not override standard "json" gem behavior?

```
require "rubygems"
gem "json"
require "json"

class Time
  def to_json(options = nil)
    "custom string"
  end
end

hash = { :x => Time.now }

puts hash.to_json # => {"x":custom string}

gem "activesupport"
require "active_support/core_ext/object" # Somewhere into Rails internals

puts Time.now.to_json # => custom string

puts hash.to_json # => {"x":"2011-02-14T16:30:10+05:00"}
```

Expected: after require "active_support/core_ext/object" I wanna get {"x":custom string} result.

Answer (score 1):

Rails since v2.3.3 switched to #as_json due to some significant reasons. So dance with it.

http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2009/7/20/rails-2-3-3-touching-faster-json-bug-fixes

Comment: Yes, Rails uses as_json, so "active_support/json" should be required before any monkeypatch and I should override as_json method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define

```
class Time
  def to_json(options = nil)
    "custom string"
  end
end
```

after

```
gem "activesupport"
require "active_support/core_ext/object"
```

code.

Comment: No success. As you can see Time#to_json works as expected. It's a problem with a hash. I am afraid that I should override a lot of AS code.

Comment: @sam try `ActiveSupport.use_standard_json_time_format = false`. If you amke it false you will get `puts hash.to_json # => {"x":"2011/02/14 17:20:53 +0530"}`

Comment: there is no such file in Rails3.

Comment: Well, "alias as_json to_json" is a solution. But I just considered to not override anything. Sometimes I hate all this magick crap.

Answer (score 0):

How about formatting your `Time.now` value with `strftime` like `Time.now.strftime("format")` for the formatting string please see the [Ruby Docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000392).

Or if you don't really want to format it, just use it as a string call `Time.now.to_s`

Comment: @dombez I think he wants the time format of .to_json to be different from the default "2011-02-14T16:30:10+05:00" to a format of his desire so that when he calls User.first.to_json, he will get created_at and updated_at in this format and not do .strftime for every record he takes.